# Switching locale

Tags: flutter, flutter-intl

I followed the [guide](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization) on localization and it is working great. But I would like the user to be able to change to a locale in the app that is different from the local of the device. Can I somehow just set the locale for the app and have the entire app switch to using this locale?

I tried experimenting with "localeResolutionCallback" but without luck. Any ideas on how I can do this?

Thank you
Søren

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The is no need to use localeResolutionCallback.

You can simply specify the locale like this:

```
Locale _locale = Locale(Platform.localeName);
        @override
        Widget build(BuildContext context) {
          return MaterialApp(
            locale: _locale,
            home: const WelcomePage(),
          );
        }
```

Then you can provide the user a list of Locales to choose and create a function  like this to update the app Locale:

```
setLocale(Locale locale) {
setState(() {
  _locale = locale;
});
```

}

To call setLocale(), you can use provider or findAncestorStateOfType to expose the initial Widget (it should be stateful)

Best regards

Comment: That was so much easier than I thought, thank you

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Also I recommend getting the list of possible locales from SupportedLocales so you are always sure the selected language is there.